# configuring ntp to sync with server on local network

Tags: debian, ntp

I'm running Debian 9 on field deployed machines that don't have Internet access. I point these clients to a local ntp server at 192.168.1.10 by adding the following line to /etc/ntp.conf

```
server 192.168.1.10 prefer
```

Here is the entire file on the client:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server 192.168.1.10 prefer

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

restrict source notrap nomodify noquery
```

After running the following commands, the time is synced.

```
service ntp stop
ntpdate -u 192.168.1.10
service ntp start
```

However, on rebooting the client it goes back out of sync. Could there be a startup script that overwrites this? The system doesn't use rc.local.

Here is the output of `ntpq -pn`.

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 192.168.1.10    .XFAC.          16 u  372  256    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

The stratum of "16" shows there is an error in using the server.

- I have synced the hw clock using `timedatectl` to be nearly the same as the server. The timezone is correct.
- I have tried removing "ntp-servers" from `dhclient.conf` as in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/329614)

Still no actual sync happening though -- post reboot it follows hw clock.

Comment: vmware vms? Please edit the question for more data.

Comment: Not a vm -- machine booting debian 9

Comment: The RTC thinks its on UTC but the time isn't correct. The timezone is correct (EDT). So it subtracts the right amount from RTC but is still the wrong time. I can sync to time server using `ntpdate -u` and get correct time but it doesn't set the RTC and doesn't persist after reboot.

Comment: I can get the hardware clock to show nearly the right time using timedatectl but it still doesn't seem to be sync with the server unless I explicitly use `ntpdate -u`. It appears as if my /etc/ntp.conf is ignored.

Comment: How much time difference you get after reboot? Is it minutes or hours? If it's hours, is it the same difference as UTC-EDT? Does it happen to all clients after rebooting?

Comment: Time difference is in the order of seconds, the difference from manually setting hw clocks. The problem is, it appears the actual sync isn't happening by ntpd -- and neither is the hw clock being set for successive reboots.